# What's closing my port?

Tags: solaris, serial, sunray

I've got some software that's running on Solaris 10 servers.  We're using SunRays as the clients.  The software uses the SunRay serial ports to communicate with some manufacturing equipment.  At one particular location, on one particular server, we've started getting intermittent "This Port is Closed" errors.  Of course, nothing that we can think of has changed recently (no updates to  the OS, our software, or the equipment).  Is there a way to log/track serial port open/closes?

Comment: It's probably a network issue, have you pulled the switch's records of errors/etc on the port?

Comment: It's a serial port.  Not a network port.

Comment: This is a serial port connected to one of the RunRay Clients right?

Comment: Correct, the serial port on the SunRay client.  Supposedly no connection drops on the session, trying to find logs to verify that now (been running so flawlessly for so long that I can't remember how to do much in it anymore.  :-)  ).  Unfortunately it's located on the opposite of the continent from me, so "go and see" troubleshooting is challenging...

Comment: You could probably monitor it via dtrace, but I don't know which probes to use for that.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps some sort of file close probe on /tmp/SUNWut/units/IEEE802.xxxxxxxxxxxxx/devices/serial:a?  Thoughts?  Pointers to some quick get started/cheat sheets for DTrace?  I've always been interested in what it could do, but have never had to use it before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't had time to pursue figuring how to use DTrace to figure out the problem yet.  In the meantime, the SunRay at that location failed and they swapped in a new one.  Problem has disappeared since the replacement.  So, perhaps a hardware issue, or perhaps something wonky happened to the OS (perhaps a reboot would have solved the issue with the old SunRay).